# Unmarshall JAXB child with different namespace

Tags: xsd, namespaces, jaxb, unmarshalling

I am new to XML and JAXB. I have read a lot about XML, namespace declaration and so on but I currently face a problem with JAXB I can not solve. There is a [XSD file](http://ops.epo.org/3.1/schema/rplus.xsd) about a response document on the EPO. I can call the EPO web service with my client and get a return document. I'll show the first lines of such a returned document.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='/3.0/style/rplus.xsl' ?>
<ns2:world-patent-data 
    xmlns:ns2="http://ops.epo.org" 
    xmlns:ns3="http://www.epo.org/register" 
    xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    xmlns:ns5="http://www.epo.org/cpcexport" 
    xmlns:ns6="http://www.epo.org/cpcdefinition">
    <ns2:meta name="elapsed-time" value="15"/>
    <ns2:register-search total-result-count="1">
        <ns2:query syntax="CQL">application=EP99203729</ns2:query>
        <ns2:range begin="1" end="1"/>
        <ns3:register-documents produced-by="RO">
            <ns3:register-document date-produced="20151028" dtd-version="1.0" lang="en" produced-by="RO" status="NO OPPOSITION FILED WITHIN TIMELIMIT">
                ...
            </ns3:register-document>
        </ns3:register-documents>
    </ns2:register-search>
</ns2:world-patent-data >
```

As you can see, there are multiple namespaces defined but only two that are used in the body of the document, i.e. ns2 and ns3. My problem is to unmarshall the ns3:register-documents entity. I used Netbeans to create my JAXB classes. The [XSD file](http://ops.epo.org/3.1/schema/rplus.xsd) from EPO was used. Netbeans only created the classes belonging to this XSD, i.e. there are no n2:register-search or n2:world-patent-data classes generated. I have tried following: I tried to unmarshall the whole document and supposed that the JAXB unmarshaller will find the ns3:register-documents element automatically, identifiy it as root and return it. I also tried to extract the ns3:register-documents element from the XML document using XPATH and unmarshall only this element. This also does not work. A **javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element** is thrown. I suppose that I have to tell JAXB, where the ns3:register-documents starts, to which namespace it belongs etc. etc. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do it. Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score -1):

You might have downloaded all XML Schemas from that corner and generated all Java classes, including those for the communication layer. However, I can sympathize with you, avoiding all that extra hassle :-)

But now you'll have to do a little explicit XML handling: parse the XML into a DOM tree, get the node you are interested in and unmarshal from that. Here's how:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    Document document = db.parse(new File( "xxx.xml" ) );
    Element rootNode = document.getDocumentElement();
    if (! rootNode.getLocalName().equals("world-patent-data")) {
        throw new IllegalStateException( "bad document" );
    }
    NodeList infos = 
        rootNode.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://ops.epo.org", "register-search");
    if( infos.getLength() == 0 ){
        throw new IllegalStateException( "not a register search" );
    }   
    Element info = (Element)infos.item(0);
    NodeList docs = 
        info.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.epo.org/register", "register-documents");
    if( docs.getLength() == 0 ){
        throw new IllegalStateException( "no register-documents" );
    }   
    Element newTop = (Element)docs.item(0);
    System.out.println( newTop.getTagName() );
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( "org.epo.register" );
    Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    JAXBElement jbe = 
        (JAXBElement)u.unmarshal( newTop );
    RegisterDocuments rds = jbe.getValue();
    System.out.println( rds.getProducedBy() );
```